# Reducing a matrix of rank $r$ to a product of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

In problem set 2.2, question 28 of the book *Linear Algebra and its Applications by Gilbert Strang*, we are asked to express a matrix $A$ of rank $r$ as a product of two matrices:

1. A matrix containing the pivot columns of $A$ and
2. A matrix containing the first $r$ rows of $R$.

For instance,

$$
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 3 & 3 & 2\\2 & 6 & 9 & 7\\ -1 & -3 & 3 & 4\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 3\\2 & 9\\ -1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 3 & 0 & -1\\0 & 0 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$

Why is this possible and what is the significance of such a representation?

Comment: $R $ being the reduced row echelon form of $A $?

Comment: @AnyAD Yes, it is the row reduced echelon form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns that have pivots are the linearly independent columns of $A $. So all other columns of $A $ are linear combinations of these. The matrix with non-zero rows from the reduced form contain the relevant coefficients of linear dependence (for each column that can be expressed as a linear combination of the linearly independent/pivot set). The pivot columns in the matrix when premultiplied by the matrix of pivot columns simply extract the pivot columns.